# In calling method why Exception can be caught without throwing and why subclass of exception cannot be caught without throwing

Tags: java, exception

Catching an exception for a method which does not throw a subclass of exception in try block, fails to compile. when I catch Exception it works. How does it work??

This code below does not compile !!

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            myMethod();
        } catch(MyException ex) {//Does not compile
        }
    }

    public static void myMethod() {}
}
```

class MyException extends Exception {}

---

But when Exception is caught, compiler does not complain.

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{
            myMethod();
        } catch(Exception ex) {//how does this works ??
        }
    }

    public static void myMethod() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [JLS (§11.2.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3): (emphasis mine)

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked
>   exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block
>   corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class
>   that is a subclass or superclass of E1, **unless E1 is Exception or a
>   superclass of Exception**.

Comment: And the reason is that [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) is a subclass of `Exception`, so catching `Exception` also means catching un-checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`MyException` is a checked exception. It was never thrown from your `myMethod()` method . So catch block will be unreachable.

But `Exception` is a super class of checked and unchecked(runtime) exception and if any runtime exception thrown from myMethod() it will be handled in catch block
which is a possible scenario. Hence there is no compilation error.

Comment: Why downvote??? What is wrong in my answer ? You should always explain before downvoting